# Javascript: For in loops iterating over properties or indices?

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Just started learning Javascript. Recently I used a for-in loops to iterate over properties of an object. For example...

```
var someObject = { a:1, b:2 };

for(var property in someObject){
    console.log(property);
}
```

This would print...

```
"a"
"b"
```

However, when I use it to iterate over an array...

```
var someArray = ["a","b","c"];

for(var element in someObject){
    console.log(element);
}
```

The indices, rather than the elements, get printed...

```
"0"
"1"
"2"
```

Why is this the case? In general, do JS for-in loops print properties only when iterated over objects and indices for everything else?

If it prints indices with the exception of objects, why would one ever use a classic for loop such as

```
for(var i=0,i<someNumber,i++)
```

when one can just use a for in loop? Especially since this seems a lot more concise?

```
for(var i in something)
```

Am I even supposed to use for-in loops for anything besides objects?

Thanks!

Comment: yep, its all because array its object like this {1:'a', 2:'b' ...}

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
>   integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
>   properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
>   indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
>   properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
>   inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
>   over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
>   it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach
>   or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where
>   the order of access is important.

So, Don't rely on `for..in` for iterating over an Array.

And to answer

> The indices, rather than the elements, get printed... Why is this the
>   case?

The answer has already been quoted above.

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
>   are otherwise identical to general Object properties.

To confirm that fact, try the following sample code

```
var myArray = ["A", "B", "C"];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    console.log(myArray.hasOwnProperty(i));   // will print true
}
```

That is why `for..in` works with Arrays as well.